# Call php function from js in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pass some data from js to a PHP function in a WordPress plugin I'm currently developing, but I'm not sure if this is the way of doing it. Essentially what I want to achieve is as follows:

1. Send a post or get via js when clicking a button.
2. In PHP, if that post/get has no error, call a function. and show an "OK"-response message.
3. It has error show an "error"-response message.

As it works now is that it always returns 0 and I don't know how to access the response correctly. Can anyone help me here? All of this is happening in the wp-admin area if that matters. Below is the code.

**functions.php:**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_post_type_search_callback', 'my_callback');

function my_callback() {
  $data= $_POST['variable'];

  $output= 'i was returned with ajax';
  //need to echo output and exit here ?
  echo $output;
  exit();
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#import_posts').on('click', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
      action: 'my_callback',
      variable: 45
    },
    success: function (output) {
     $('.response').html(output);
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
  <button id="import_posts" class="button button-primary button-large">Submit</button>
  <div class="response">
    response
  </div>
```

Comment: `//do i need this?` – yes, you do - but with different values, because right now the function/method name you are specifying there, does not match that of your actual function. If you don’t know how the WordPress hook / filter system works to begin with, you should go and properly read up on that first.

Comment: To be slightly more direct than the comment above, there is nothing currently in your  PHP code which would cause the `my_callback()` function to be executed. Therefore no output will be created.

Comment: Hi, i have now added the correct action. I do know the action/filter concept. Just was not unsure wheter i needed to use it or not. Code updated. When running it now i get the error: "400. bad request" when calling admin-ajax.php @ADyson

Comment: `array($this, 'my_callback')` is wrong, you are not trying to call a static method of some class here, you have just a plain function. So this needs to be _just_ `'my_callback'` - no $this, no array.

Comment: Thanks, changed. I still get "400 (Bad Request)" on admin-ajax.php tho.

Comment: In your JS, `action` should be `post_type_search_callback` instead of `my_callback`. That's likely why you're getting `Bad Request` responses from the server.

Comment: @cabrerahector That did the job. Thanks! Now I get "0" in my response. Not sure if thats whats suppose to happen. Is it?

Comment: OOOOK.. finally got it working. Thanks for all help and pointers mates!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, @mathias5. That way someone else who might having a similar issue could benefit from it in the future.

Comment: Will do. Just a moment.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

You passes action in JS file "my_callback" but in PHP file there is not such a action is available. You need to change this line.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_search_callback', array($this, 'my_action_post_type_search_callback'));
```

Also if possible than pass dynamic path of admin-ajax.php file so you can use this file from any of you site's page. Current integration will only work for home page. You can get the path of the admin-ajax.php via wp's default function called `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>`

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code with the corect action. But when running it i get the error: "400. bad request" when calling admin-ajax.php. Can you elaborate your answer slightly ? Edited my code.

Comment: In wordpress we needs to use add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_search_callback', array($this, 'my_action_post_type_search_callback')); this action also if you are trying to use your ajax call without user login. So, please try this. If this also not works then please provide your source code.